# Ruby - Replace array with a string inside a hashtable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, hash

I'd like to convert the following hash...

```
a = {
  "foo": {
    "bar": {
      "baz": [
        "22"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

to:

```
a = {
  "foo": {
    "bar": {
      "baz": "22"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

When I run:

```
puts "DEBUG: #{a['foo']['bar']['baz'].join(',')}"
```

the output is ok.

However when I try to replace the array inside the hash like this:

```
a['foo']['bar']['baz'].join!(',')
```

It dies with:

hash.rb:18:in `<main>': undefined method`join!' for ["22"]:Array (NoMethodError)

Any hint would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: remove the `!` in `join!`

Comment: This way it just outputs the exact same hash with a['foo']['bar']['baz'] as an array.

Comment: You need to assign it back to `..["baz"]`

Comment: What you have is not a Ruby hash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do:

```
a['foo']['bar']['baz'] = a['foo']['bar']['baz'].join(',')
```

You can't change a class of the object, hence there is no bang version of `join`

Comment: Worth noting that the mutating (!) method can't exist because `join` will produce a `String`, from an `Array`, so for the variable itself to be changed, its class would have to be changed, which cannot be done.